# Input file comparison not working Python

Tags: python

1. Why is the removal of the double quotes not working? (country = country[1:-1])
2. Why is the `first_list.append` line not executing? I am looping through the lines of an input file and matching it against the first element of a list of lists stored in final_lists. When I print the output, even when the two values are in fact the same verified by the print statements (for example, when row[0]==Zimbabwe AND country==Zimbabwe) the next append statement does not run.

---

```
with open('world_bank_regions.tsv', 'rU') as f:
    next(f)

    for line in f:
         [region, subregion, country] = line.split('\t')

        if country.startswith('"') and country.endswith('"'):
            country = country[1:-1]

        print country #the double quotes remain

        for row in final_list: #final list is a list of lists 
            print row[0]    #row[0] == Zimbabwe
            print country   #country == Zimbabwe
            if row[0] == country:
                final_list.append([region, subregion])

    print final_list #no changes were made to the list from the previous steps
```

Comment: What does the data look like? Any reason for not using the `csv` module, it can sensibly handle tab delimited files.

Comment: @AChampion the data from the input file are just three columns of strings. I didn't use the csv module because when I tried to do so earlier, I wasn't able to figure out how to directly assign them to variables as I have above (i.e. specify each row as being 'region' 'subregion' 'country') but instead had to just assign each row to a list

Comment: `for region, subregion, country in csv_reader:` would allow you to iterate a csv file assigning each row to the variables `region`, `subregion`, `country`. Can you share a few lines of the data file?

Comment: Yep, the data looks something like this (thank you for the tip about the csv reader, I will try that now!)                                                                      Europe     European Union       Austria                                                                  Africa        Western Africa         Benin

Comment: You can strip the double quotes using `country.strip('"')`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the majority of your problem by using the `csv` module. The second problem you have is that you are modifying the same list you are looping over. This is never a good idea.

To solve your first problem:

```
import csv

with open('world_bank_regions.tsv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
       print(row['Country'])
```

For your second problem, you can approach it two ways. The first is to convert it into a dictionary for fast lookups, using the country name as the key.

As the country name is the first entry in the inner lists, you can do this:

```
lookup = {i[0]: i for i in final_list}
```

Then your complete code looks like this:

```
import csv

lookup = {i[0]: i for i in final_list}

with open('world_bank_regions.tsv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
       if row['Country'] in lookup.keys():
            lookup[row['Country']] += [row['Region'], row['Subregion']]
```

`csv.DictReader` takes the first row, and uses them as keys for the data in the remaining rows and returns a dictionary when you loop over it.

The example above assumes your input file looks like this:

```
Country\tRegion\tSubregion
Zimbabwe\tAfrica\t
```